# Convert 2 dimensional table to list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using excel 2010.

I have the following table:

[image]

When using duplicate values I only get `1,2,3,4 etc.`.

Any suggestions how to create this table via a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

Formula in `G2`:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/4)+2)
```

In case you do have sequential numbers, you can use `=INT(ROW(A4)/4)`

Formula in `H2`:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,,COUNTIF($G$2:G2,G2))
```

Formula in `I2`:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$9,G2,MATCH(H2,$B$1:$E$1,0))
```

Drag all down...

[image]

Comment: The G2 formula works for this very specific case of IDs being 1,2,3...etc,  but if the IDs were not sequential and starting at 1, you may want to replace the formula with something along the lines of `INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/4)+2)`.

Comment: Good addition @ForwardEd, I assumed sequential numbers but most likely they are not :). In fact looking at OP's question again, the `7` is actually missing :)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is with `Power Query`.  In Excel 2010, if not already installed, this is a [free add-in from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379&CorrelationId=dc571dd9-ff58-4e6e-8c72-6172db112bc0).

Once you've done that:

- select some cell in your original table
- select to get Data `from Table/Range`
- When the UI opens

  - select the ID column
  - select `Transform-->Unpivot-->Other columns`
- Close & Load

If you add data to your original table, just Refresh the Query.

[image]

Comment: Nice Ron, it's such a usefull tool!