# Will it be possible to transpose columns in an excel to rows and have duplicate rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the columns in my current excel like this. The column header for example 2019-03 represents March 2019 and the rows of that column contains prices of the homes corresponding to a particular city. I am unable to do a time series analysis(On kepler.gl) on this as the months are in columns. Will it be possible to transpose the columns to rows and have duplicate rows for each city with a corresponding price?

What I intend to have is a column called Timeline with months as rows and you can see the corresponding price of a house in a particular time period and for a particular city. Since its only 2 rows, I have done it manually here. There are many such columns in the file I have. Is there a better way to achieve this is in excel?  I would at least need the data from 2015. So that will be a huge task. Was wondering if there was a better way to solve this. Please let me know.

```
Actual Data

2019-03  2019-04  2019-05  2019-06   City
548400   563600   585100   595000    Leland
118100   118700   119300   125000    Barron
```

Expected table in excel

```
Timeline  Price    City
2019-03   548400   Leland
2019-04   563600   Leland
2019-05   585100   Leland
2019-06   595000   Leland
2019-03   118100   Barron
2019-04   118700   Barron
2019-05   119300   Barron
2019-06   125000   Barron
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PowerQuery or formulas instead of VBA:

**PowerQuery:**

- Select a cell in your > Data > From Table/Range
- Select City column > Transform > Unpivot > Other columns
- Close PowerQuery and load data

*Credits to @RonRosenfeld who described this very clear* **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700106/convert-2-dimensional-table-to-list/56700307#56700307)** *including a link for a free add-in on Excel-2010!*

[image]

**Formulas:**

On that same page I described the use of formulas. In your case you could use:

Formula in `G2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$D$3,MATCH(I2,$E$2:$E$3,0),MATCH(H2,$A$1:$D$1,0))
```

Formula in `H2`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$1,,COUNTIF($I$2:I2,I2))
```

Formula in `I2`:

```
=INDEX(E:E,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/4)+2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton JvdV! Worked perfectly fine!